# Postman cannot complete the request on using its evironment variable for jwt

Tags: node.js, express, rest, jwt, postman

I m making a rest api using node, express for a project wherein first the user signups or login and gets a JWT token in response. Using that JWT token received on signup or login , the user can access some of the protected routes of my application.

When i try to set a evironment variable in postman named **jwt** for authorization with that token, then request to that particular protected route ( Get all tours ) which needs the user to be authorized or loggedin before accessing it doesn't gets completed , it just shows "sending request" .

Here's my controller for protected routes:

```
   exports.protect = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1) Getting the token & checking if it's there
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    console.log(token);
  }

  if (!token) {
    return next(
      new AppError('You are not logged in. Please login to access', 401)
    );
  }
  // 2) Verification of the token
  // const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET); //decoded is the payload of the jwt
  let decoded;
  try {
    decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    console.log(decoded);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next(err);
  }

  // 3) Check if user still exists
  const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
  console.log(currentUser);
  if (!currentUser) {
    return next(
      new AppError('The user belongining to this token does not exist.', 401)
    );
  }

  // 4) Check if user changed the password after the token was issued
  if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
    return new AppError(
      'User recently changed password. Please login again.',
      401
    );
  }

  //GRANT ACCESS TO THE PROTECTED ROUTE
  req.user = currentUser;
  next();
});
```

The result of first console.log(**req.headers.authorization**) is :  `'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0NzM0YzY1Yzc0ZDUyNzJhMDQwYWQ2ZSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTQyOTc1MCwiZXhwIjoxNjkzMjA1NzUwfQ.b-x0SH1GAFmQ7ZrDGzgqcd2HShDwclmb7d4oKk6lDlk',`

The result of second console.log(**token**) is : `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0NzM0YzY1Yzc0ZDUyNzJhMDQwYWQ2ZSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTQyOTc1MCwiZXhwIjoxNjkzMjA1NzUwfQ.b-x0SH1GAFmQ7ZrDGzgqcd2HShDwclmb7d4oKk6lDlk`

The result of third console.log(**decoded**) is : `{ id: '64734c65c74d5272a040ad6e', iat: 1685432169, exp: 1693208169 }`

The result of fourth console.log(**currentUser**) is : `{ _id: new ObjectId("64734c65c74d5272a040ad6e"), name: 'John', email: 'john@gmail.com', __v: 0 }`

Allthe results are as expected and correct.

In the code when i use "Authorization" instead of "authorization" , the request in the postman get completed but the code cannot read the value of req.headers.Authorization because "Authorization" is always undefined as the property in the req.headers is called "authorization". With the "Authorization" i always get the error from my error controller that "Your are not logged in" although i m logged in and have a vaild JWT token .

Here are my postman screenshots :
[image]

[image]

[image]

I compared my code with the Instructors code as well through which i m learning and the code is same. I think that theres some postman issue although my postman is uptodate. I spent hours of debugging and figured out that the problem is with "Authorization" only in the code . The postman completes the request when i use "Authorization" instead of "authorization" but always give me error as user not logged in to access the protected route. On the other hand when i use "authorization" as the actuall code is from the instructor, the request in postman doesn't gets completed...
Any help would be grateful :)

Comment: Keys in `req.headers` are _always_ lowercased, no matter how they were sent in the request.

Comment: Your code expects the token in the format `Bearer TOKEN`, append Bearer to the token and try again

Comment: @SuleymanSah OP is using the _"Bearer Token"_ option in Postman. You can see it in the third screenshot

Comment: @Phil yaa i got to know that but if i dont use Authorization in the code , the request in the postman doesn't gets completed....that's the overall issue

Comment: @Phil tried it , still not working , as you suggested but the execution of the code is not reaching till the second part of my code where i m using promisify

Comment: 'You are not logged in! Please log in to get access.' case happens if the condition ( req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) is false. Can you add `console.log(req.headers.authorization)`?

Comment: Sure here's what it logs :` {
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0NzM0YzY1Yzc0ZDUyNzJhMDQwYWQ2ZSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTQyOTc1MCwiZXhwIjoxNjkzMjA1NzUwfQ.b-x0SH1GAFmQ7ZrDGzgqcd2HShDwclmb7d4oKk6lDlk',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.32.2',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': '658b6910-8698-47dd-b975-3e901a5d7f83',
  host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}`

Comment: Good, and what is the result of `console.log(token)` after line `token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];`

Comment: @SuleymanSah The result of token is the actual jwt token which is expected the string after the Bearer. The only issue is that the request is not been competed in the postman . it just shows "sending request" and keeps buffering

Comment: @Phil I got u mate but i already provided all the information and now all the logs that i get .. My code never reaches the decoded variable part as the request is not been completed in the postman and if it gets so by using **Authorization** it sends response as the error and gets done.

Comment: Done @Phil check now

Comment: @Phil The code doesn' t reaches that part of the code ... i have been telling you this from the start....after loging the token ....the code just stops from executing and the request in the postman just keeps buffering saying "sending request....." even after logging the token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253876/discussion-between-neilson-programmer-and-phil).

Comment: @Phil done as you said ... i request lets discuss this in chat

Comment: How do you know `currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)` doesn't fail? Adding one more `console.log("User validated!")` before that final `next()` would tell you. Otherwise, the error isn't even in the middleware code and is probably in your route handlers. They must **always** call `res.send()` or `next()`

Comment: Okk i did that and it dosen't logs that means the issue is with the fourth part of my code right??

Comment: Looks like a pretty simple mistake. You should be passing that last error to `next()`, not returning it directly. Next time don't assume that your code _stops_ anywhere without directly verifying that with either a debugger or logging

Comment: Like which error are you talking about to pass into the next() ....according to me if all the four steps from the code are successfull then only the next() should be called that will run the code from the next middleware of for that route from the middleware stack

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here...

> ```js
> if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
>    return new AppError(
>      'User recently changed password. Please login again.',
>      401
>    );
>  }
> ```

Returning directly from your middleware without calling `next()` or `res.send()` causes Express to never send a response.

You'll want to match the previous error handling patterns and use the following

```js
if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
  return next(
    new AppError("User recently changed password. Please login again.", 401)
  );
}
```

---

As for why that might be invalidating the `iat` property, keep in mind that JavaScript timestamps are measured in milliseconds.

`1685432169` is `1970-01-20T12:10:32.169Z` but `1685432169 * 1000` is `2023-05-30T07:36:09.000Z`

Comment: got it . Thanks for the your time . It took nearly two days to identify this small mistake. You really helped me out :)